# Подскажите как правильно указать правило в .htaccess

Tags: регулярные-выражения, apache

Всем привет! 
У меня в .htaccess прописано правило при котором все маршруты с доменом .ru должны перенаправляться на те же маршруты только с доменом .com

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.ru
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.ru
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

В принципе здесь все ок, кроме одного - мне нужно добавить исключение для одной(в будущем возможно нескольких) страницы.  Как это правильно сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.ru
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/news/1/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/news/2/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.ru
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Адреса имеющие вид

```
http://domain.ru/news/1/
http://domain.ru/news/2/
http://www.domain.ru/news/1/
http://www.domain.ru/news/2/
http://domain.ru/news/1/привет-мир
http://domain.ru/news/2/вторая-новость/
```

не будут переадресовываться на `.com`.